# How useful is loopback interface statistics retrieved from SNMP

Tags: snmp

Is loopback statistics retrieved using SNMP really useful to a customer?

Answer (score -2):

Sure.

Its more important that file count on root file system.

Comment: You might want to provide some reasoning for this.